# When to Request Contact Info in Survey?

Tags: information, surveys

My business (B2B) created an online survey to be used for lead generation and to show potential customers why they need our services. We need to collect some user information (name, email, company) for lead generation and I am wondering if there is a general rule for at what point to request contact information.

The user info could be requested at the welcome page of the survey before the first question, or at the end of the survey before results are displayed. This information could also be required for the user to proceed, or simply be requested and not required.

My thought is to require this information from the user at the start of the survey, that way we will have contact info for every person who takes the survey. If the user information were to be required at the end of the survey before results are displayed the user may end up feeling trapped and leave the page.

Is there a proper point when the user information should be requested in the survey?
Thank you.

Comment: Would vote for hidden option 3: Survey-->Feedback-->Collect Info. `Show potential customers why they need your services,` _then_ ask if they'd like to be contacted. No-pressure sales pitch.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, no, you can request what you want, when you want it.

However, if you adopt the idea that you can request contact information up front, you'll likely get a lot more false information.  People don't want to enter their data unless they want to be contacted.  If they haven't yet taken your survey, they don't yet know if they want you to contact them or not, so they'll be less likely to enter real info.

Worse, you may put them off from even taking the survey.  Many people would rather get nothing from your site, and would rather visit someone else's site than give you their information.

If you request the info at the end of the survey, you will likely get info from the people who are genuinely interested in hearing from you. If someone abandons your site before entering their data, they are likely not interested in your services anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need too much information from the user to get in contact? If so, be careful on asking all of it at first before giving them more information about your business and product.

Are you creating a landing page to validate a startup product/service to be developed? If so, in my tests we did offer articles which explains more about it to people who did finish the survey.